# Is the size of a 1 dimensional vector space over a finite field the same size as the field?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $F$ is a finite field and $V$ is a vector space over $F$, then:

1. If $V$ is $1$ dimensional, is it true that $|V| = |F|$?
2. If 1. is true, is there any example of such $V$ where $V$ is not a field isomorphic to $F$?
3. If $V$ is $n$ dimensional, is it true that $|F|$ divides $|V|$?

Comment: $V$ has not have to be a field...

Comment: 1 and 3.  are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. If $\{v\}$ is any basis for $V$, then $V=\{ av \mid a \in F\}$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $F$.
2. $V$ need not be a field, since it need not have any notion of multiplication. For instance, let $F=\mathbb{R}$, and let $V= \{(x,x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then $V$ is a 1-dimensional vector space over $F$, but $V$ is not a field. It does not make sense to ask what $(2,2)$ times $(5,5)$ is or what $(3,3)^{-1}$ is. However, you could always define a multiplication and a multiplicative identity on $V$ that makes it a field isomorphic to $F$. In this example, we could choose the multiplicative identity to be $(1,1)$ and define $(x,x)\cdot(y,y) = (xy,xy)$.
3. Yes, if $F$ is finite, then $|V|=|F|^n$. You can argue this by extending the correspondence I described in part 1.

Comment: Why must the elements of {av | a in F} all distinct? Can’t there be distinct a,b in F, where av = bv?

Comment: @ccopyu It follows from $1v=v$. If $av=bv$, then $(a-b) v=0$. If $a-b\neq 0$, then you could multiply by some element of $F$ to get $1v$, and it follows that $v=0$.